# Differentiating a 1-form along a path

Tags: differential-geometry

Suppose $\omega$ is a 1-form on a manifold $M$ and $c:(-\epsilon,\epsilon)\rightarrow TM$
is a path.

Write $c(t)=(a(t),b(t))$ so $b(t)\in T_{a(t)}M$. What
is the correct answer for

$$\frac{d}{dt}\omega(c(t))=\frac{d}{dt}\omega_{a(t)}(b(t))?$$

Answer (score 1):

How have you tried doing this? Are you using local coordinates or are you trying to use a more intrinsic approach? (For the latter, you might consider interpreting your expression as a Lie derivative. Note that your $\omega$ can, by pullback, be considered a $1$-form on $TM$, rather than on $M$.)